# jquery event not firing on second click

Tags: jquery

I have html as below. i want to add toggle functionality where div with class=togglediv should be shown or hidden on click of header with class=grid-1of1.

Issue is the first click when i open the toggle works fine. But when i again click on header to hide the div the click event is not getting fired.

HTMl:

```
<div class="thead clearfix commonHeader">
               <div class="gs grid-1of1 hcell pointer">
                            <p>Sales<span class="icn"></span></p>
                        </div>
                <div class="togglediv" style="display: block;">
                <div id="salesProductsMultiDiv" class="clearfix ms-shim">
                    <p class="loader center hide"><img class="loadingIcon" src="/resources/images/spinner.gif"></p>

    <div class="vError mls pll hide" data-id="salesProductsMulti"><span class="mll">Please select a product</span></div>
    <select id="salesProductsMulti" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
    <option value="iphone" data-id="iphone" title="iPhone">iPhone </option><option value="ipad" data-id="ipad" title="iPad" selected="selected">iPad </option><option value="mac" data-id="mac" title="Mac" selected="selected">Mac </option><option value="ipod" data-id="ipod" title="iPod" selected="selected">iPod </option><option value="appletv" data-id="appletv" title="Apple TV" selected="selected">Apple TV </option><option value="beats" data-id="beats" title="Beats">Beats </option><option value="watch" data-id="watch" title="Watch">Watch </option><option value="watchedition" data-id="watchedition" title="Watch Edition">Watch Edition </option>
    </select><div id="ms-salesProductsMulti" class="ms-container"><div class="ms-selectable" data-id="salesProductsMulti"><input type="text" class="multiselect-filter field-input field-text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Available Products"><ul class="ms-list ms-focus"><li class="ms-elem-selectable" id="_i_p_h_o_n_e_-selectable"><span>iPhone </span></li></ul></div></div>
</div>

                <div class="clearfix field-block channelInputText">
                    <label class="h-label" for="salesSearchRadius">Search Radius</label>
                    <input class="h-input input-n field-input field-text" type="text" value="" data-id="salesSearchRadius" maxlength="35" id="salesSearchRadius">
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix field-block channelInputText">
                    <label class="h-label" for="salesMaxResults">Max Results</label>
                    <input class="h-input input-n field-input field-text" type="text" value="" data-id="salesMaxResults" maxlength="35" id="salesMaxResults">
                </div>
                </div>
             </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.commonHeader .grid-1of1').off('click').on("click", function(event) {            
                var $this = event.currentTarget;
                if($($this).is('.grid-1of1')){
                    $($this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('togglediv')).toggle();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Remove `off('click')`

Comment: `var $this = event.currentTarget`: I would believe jQuery does this for you.

Comment: this seems to be working on my end.

Comment: do you have any errors in console, what browser are you working on?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue in your code. I have also created http://jsfiddle.net/xz8x7oma/ for reference

Comment: it might be getElementsByClassName it not supported in ie8 and lower

Comment: i m checking in safari

Comment: i think you should post the full code. obviously something else is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x88qy5c/8/) working example.

```
 $('.commonHeader .grid-1of1').click(function () {

     $(this).parent().find('.togglediv').toggle();

});
```